# Converting various file sizes to bytes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a column of "file sizes" that has been output poorly, as in it's not consistent. For example values may be, "4GB", "32 MB", "320 KB", "932 bytes", etc. I need to convert these all to a standard value so that I can add them up for a report.

Comment: Please post what did you try, and what was the result.

Comment: Without proper underlying data, your values are going to be poorly misrepesented. When expressed in terms of GB, does 499MB consume 0 or 1GB? What about `932 bytes`? ... how many bytes are in ~4GB of data? 4294967296 or 4400000000 or 3900000000 .... just something to consider. Use rough rounding and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this approach

- pick one display format. Perhaps choose bytes.

For each cell:

- determine its scale. This would likely involve string parsing, looking for "ends with" some valid range of possibilities : "bytes", "kb", "mb", "gb", "kilobytes", "gigabytes". Convert to lower case first, to ensure sanity. Consider misspellings as well!
- extract the number. Use a variation of this [VBA numeric regex](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showpost.php?s=25b73e2dfb5d4f5f91e1e2538a6be71e&p=783495&postcount=6) to extract out the numbers. Watch out for decimals!
- your output will be (the number) * (the scale in bytes)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very unsophisticated answer - but it might make this a very quick fix for you, if exact byte counts are not all important. Just do a simple text search and replace.

Replace "KB" (and "kilobytes" and other variations) with "000", "MB" with "000000" and "GB" with "000000000". "bytes" you replace with "". Then convert the cell/column type to numeric.

It won't be as easy if the values are given with decimals ("4.32 MB"), but your examples should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have two options:

1: require that all this data be in units of bytes (probably not feasible if the data already exists)

2: use a regex to separate the number from the unit, then use a switch statement (or loop or whatever you like) to perform the correct multiplications to get the number in bytes (probably the easier of the two).

edit :

the regex would look something like this :

```
(\d*) *(.*)
```

This will capture the numbers and units separately and ignore any whitespace between the two (you will still need to trim the input to the regex, as preceding and proceeding whitespace can cause some grief).

Answer (score 0):

Bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, etc. are all metric units. Just pick a standard unit for your report (say, megabytes), and multiply or divide values given in different units to get the values you need.